# After submitting app from organizer app is not displying in Activity of iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, xcode-organizer

I just want to upload new build of my app. For that I uploaded through Xcode organizer. 
After receiving confirmation from organizer screen that "Upload Successful". I checked in Activity of iTunes connect tab, at that I've seen that my particulate build and version of app is under processing. 
But suddenly after 2-5 mins whole build and version information was disappear from same screen. Just like I've never upload that build and version. First I thought may be it's update from Apple Inc. But after 8-10 hours of upload build and versions are still not appearing in same place. 
So how can I invite testers using testFlight?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to validate the build before submitting it to App store. This will let you know if there are some problems in the build.
2. Make sure the provisioning profile and code signing identity are the correct one you can check this by clicking **Save for App Store Submission** option.
3. When you have the build uploaded the iTunes connect. Click on TestFlight beta testing, select the build you want to test and click start testing. You can invite two type of testers to test flight. One are known as **internal testers**, these testers are iTunes connect users. Other are **external testers**, you can add unto 1000 external testers by specifying their email. The external testing requires **Beta Review** of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I had migrated the project from swift 2.0  to swift 3.0, and in IOS 10 new rules is implement that you must give permission for privacy setting. Bellow is the link [Requesting Permission Privacy Settings in iOS 10.](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/09/infoplist-privacy-settings-in-ios-10.html)

So when I add some privacy setting related to my project and then Upload app again so error is solve...